# Unable to point Domain to the right public_html in Centos web panel and AWS

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos7

I have:

- Set AWS EC2 Instance for Centos 7 up
- Installed Centos Web Panel.
- Associated an Elastic IP to my Insance
- In Route 53 of AWS I added a record for my domain which was pointing to the Static IP of my instance.
- And in My Domain DNS I provided Nameservers provided by AWS Route 53 for my instance.
- I created a new Account in Centos WP and provided the domain.

But still when I open the domain in browser it is loading default Apache page in Centos that is in `/usr/local/apache/htdocs/index.html`.
which should actually point to `/home/username/public_html/index.php`

I tried to:

- Manually edit the `httpd.conf` file in Apache
- And point domain to user directory

I succeeded, but then the all .php files in that directory started to give 500 Internal error, I think it may be a problem of Nameservers but I don't have any clue,

Can anyone point me to right direction to setup a website in Centos Webpanel in AWS?

My Virtual Hosts Configuration, this is what I tried to put in httpd.conf but when 500 Error started to come I had to remove it.

```
# vhost_start devo.gq
<VirtualHost 52.56.234.217:80>
ServerName devo.gq
ServerAlias www.devo.gq
ServerAdmin xxxx@gmail.com
DocumentRoot "/home/devogq/public_html"
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/devogq/public_html/cgi-bin/
# 
# Custom settings are loaded below this line (if any exist)
# Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/devogq/devo.gq/*.conf

<IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup devogq devogq
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup devogq devogq
        suPHP_ConfigPath /home/devogq
</IfModule>

<Directory "/home/devogq/public_html">
    Options all
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
# vhost_end devo.gq
```

After adding this code in httpd.conf file.
still I am still being pointed to default htdocs directory of apache.
in error logs i am getting this error
`[Sun Apr 23 17:43:04.554884 2017] [:error] [pid 16402:tid 140288731281152] [client 103.69.219.30:27233] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/devo.php`

Comment: Have you create a virtual host?

Comment: I manually edited main `httpd.conf` file and added virtual host for my new domain, it worked but then all my `.php` files in that directory started to give 500 internal error

Comment: I am using a managed centos web panel in another VPS and there I don't have to add virtual hosts manually, so I think manual entry might not be the solution, but still I am a Noob here and all solutions are welcome.

Comment: Can you post your virtual host configuration? Check also apache error log

Comment: I have posted my virtual host configuration for mydomain

Comment: Inside <Directory> add `Options all` and `Require all granted` if you use apache 2.4. Or `Allow from all` and make sure you check apache error log to understand better what is the cause.

Comment: If it is working then you can change `all` config to only allow what your app need only

Comment: Not working, tried to add options and require. didn't work then I tried to change virtual host to `<VirtualHost *:80>` it started to point every request to my user directory even for my static IP, and for the PHP file it started to give 500 error

Comment: With virtualhost point to *:80 Try with simple html first. Does it load? Make sure you chmod all files and directory with correct permission and that httpd can read them

Answer (score 1):

For me, I installed ssl and it worked.

left menu : WebServer Settings -> SSL certificates

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem with Centos Web Panel on an Oracle Virtual Box where all domains were only displaying the default test page. After trying several methods including the official ones like:
https://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/default-page-displayed-for-all-domains

*It boiled down to the IP the domain (account) was being set on.*

When creating the account, the shared public IP was chosen by default (in my case). When I changed it to use the local VM IP which the CWP was running on, they started working again. You may have to rebuild the vHosts again  (Left Menu --> Apache Settings --> Rebuild Apache vHosts); for me, I realized this after deleting all account so I did not have to rebuild them.